# How to quit reverse-i-search without moving the cursor?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, emacs

In Bash, I often encounter below situation when doing reverse-i-search (using emacs keybinding in Bash):
`(reverse-i-search:ccc) aaa bbb |ccc ddd`
I am in the middle of reverse-i-search for 'ccc', and the cursor correctly stopped at matching string.

Now I want to start from here, and add some additional characters before `ccc`, e.g. making it `eee ccc`.
However, I cannot press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, otherwise the command is directly executed;
I can neither directly enter the characters I want to add, otherwise the search string is changed;
I cannot press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, otherwise bash will quit the search but also move the cursor.

So, how should I tell bash to quit the search but leave the cursor in place?

Comment: Do the Left and Right arrows do what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with 'Esc'. Can you elaborate? Or maybe this has been improved since you asked? Is the question still valid?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It seems `Esc` now works. Possibly due to recent improvement. Thank you for bring this up.

Comment: @egmont This works as well. A bit late to reply to this. But thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are several ways to do this *now*. Some or all of them didn't work at the time the question was asked.

1. <kbd>Esc</kbd>
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Also arrow keys (left, right) move cursor from desired position by one character.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```